# adobe media server 4 cost with amazon?

Tags: actionscript-3, amazon-web-services, flash-media-server

Has anyone tried using flash media server 4 on Amazon web service? I was wondering what your experience was and the costs of running it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Adobe doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/amazon/) ([PDF version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/amazon/flashmediaserver_4.0_amazon.pdf)) gives the answer:

Sign-up for AWS with your credit card at http://www.adobe.com/go/learn_fms_aws_order_en
and you will see the prices:

USD 5.50: One-time setup fee for FMS

USD 5.00: Monthly fee for FMS

USD 0.44: Hourly charge, giving you 100 RTMFP simultaneous connections

Additionally you need to pay the "Amazon EC2 Linux/UNIX Large" instance - USD 0.34 per hour - this adds USD 250.00 or more per month according to [Amazon calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html).

[image]